# binding multiple tables on one form in c#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

please this is kind of a beginners question. I have multiple tables like 5 tables related to each other in the database. I would like to create controls on a form in c# that will bind to different tables though related and they will scroll together when I move to the next item. I am kind of confused on how to go about it.

I watched this video i=on .net that showed me how to drag and drop from data source window onto the form but it does show me the code behind which I definitely don't understand.I would appreciate it if you can  point me to a good tutorial I could follow step by step.

thanks

Comment: What is your object model? DataSet? LINQ-to-SQL? EF? what?

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to "this video" so that people know what you already saw.

Comment: I am using datasets for the main time though I intend using LINQ-Datasets to finish up

Answer (score 1):

Use the **BindingSource**. if you say tables, you are probably using a **DataSet**. Bind the first binding source to the master table. Child tables you bind by specifying a second binding source whose data source points to the first. the **DataMember** of the 2nd source must be the DataSets's DataRelation that connects the two tables. The Windows Forms designer should help you in setting the properties correctly.